# Selecting text after regex match

Tags: python, regex

I'm really stuck with regex in python. I have a string with items like this:

```
"""
(001,002) SI [SomeTag]:Element
(001,003e) LO [SomeTag2]:Element2
(001,004r) LR [SomeTag3]:Element3
(001,006) HI [SomeTag4]:Element4
"""
```

And I want to select "Element2". I tried to select the line with

```
me = re.search("\(001,003e\)(.*)", obj)
```

And it gives me the whole line. But I just want "Element2". How can I select everything in the line that regex matches (e.g "(001,003e)") that is after the ':'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can do `\(001,003e\)[^:]*:(.*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the comment above as an aswer:

You can use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and use `\(001,003e\)[^:]*:(.*)`. The second group will return 'Element2'.